# Use array key as label for UITableView row

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to use they keys from an array in a plist as the label for a table. This is what I've tried so far. 
I've declared an ivar: `NSArray *viewerKeys;`

in viewDidLoad

```
`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)plistPath];
viewerKeys = [dictionary allKeys];`
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath
    `UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    label.text = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

I can log viewerKeys from viewdidload but if i try `NSLog@"%@", [viewerKeys objectATIndex:indexPath.row]` I get nothing - not even null.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact code from `viewDidLoad` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that you are using

Comment: why dont you log `[dictionary allKeys];` it's possible that is blank

Comment: That is the exact code - as I said I get a result when I log viewerKeys (which is equal to `[dictionary allKeys]`). Although I haven't tried it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath with just viewerKeys

Comment: If `viewerKeys`  is defined as property, then just assign `self.viewerKeys  = [dictionary allKeys];`. or `[viewerKeys retain];` Not sure.Just give a try.

Comment: I've added property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *viewerKeys` and changed all references to `viewerKeys` to `self.viewerKeys`. No luck.

Comment: I don't think `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is ever being used - I just put an `NSLog` in there for a string and nothing came out...

Comment: Found the problem, i'm not counting `numberOfRowsInSection` properly. I've fixed it now. Cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't counting numberOfRowsInSection properly. My mistake!